# elasticsearch max aggregation return more than one result

Tags: elasticsearch

Im running the following query:

```
POST myindex/_search
{
"aggs": {
  "minSamp": {
    "min": {
      "field": "sample"
    }
  }
}

}
```

**part** of the result:

```
    {
      "took": 15,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 91,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
        {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "myindex",
        "_id": "HyYmY2oB06bGDsjT4C7Z",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
         "sample": 119267,
         "age": 6,
         "comp": 11
         }
       },
    {
        "_index": "myindex",
        "_type": "myindex",
        "_id": "HyYmY2oB06bGDsjT4C79",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
         "sample": 117100,
         "age": 9,
         "comp": 7
         }
       }
    ]
   }
  }
    ....
```

and I want to get only one response (what is the smallest "sample" value") 
but I get lot of documents as response, full documents ,
1. what is wrong?
2. can I get one response for multiple indices? for example: if my query is for all indices that start with "my":

Thanks

```
POST my*/_search
```

Comment: Please add result

Comment: I've added result to the question

Comment: In hits, it will be returning default 10 documents. You need to give size:0 in your query if you don't want to return documents(only aggregation is needed).

Comment: Thanks, if you want can write this as an answer so I will vote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In hits, it will be returning default 10 documents. You need to give size:0 in your query if you don't want to return documents i.e only aggregation is needed

```
"size":0,
"aggs": {
  "minSamp": {
    "min": {
      "field": "sample"
    }
  }
}
```

[link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) for reference.

Comment: Thanks, can I get the whole document with the maximum value of "sample" ?

Comment: You can sort document on sample and set size as 1.

Comment: right, so with respect to performance, in cases I need only the 'sample' max value, is it better to use aggregation OR sort and _source (_source to get only the field I want) ?

Comment: If only max value is needed, max aggregation will return it. In case document or additional fields are needed , better to sort(without aggregation) and get top 1 result(using size)

Comment: I mean:to get only the max value I can choose one of the following options: 1.'sort' and '_source' ("_source":["sample"]), 2. 'aggregation. is it better to use 'aggregation' or 'sort'?

Comment: aggregation will be better and clean